# How to Change Date Format According to User Selection?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

How can I change the date :order according to the User's "f.select :categories" choice?

For example when a User goes to the Quantified _form he can select between "Monthly Average" or "One-Time Instance";

If he selects "Monthly Average" I want the **_results_fields.html.erb** to provide the date selection as ":order => [:month, :year]" if he selects "One-Time Instance" I want the **_results_fields.html.erb** to provide the date selection as ":order => [:month, :day, :year]

Ideally this would be done dynamically via javascript, but I would be happy to accept an answer that does it via the view.

**_results_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :result_value, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Result' %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.date_select :date_value, :order => [:month, :year], class: 'date-select' %>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Result", f %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```ruby
<%= form_for @quantified do |f| %>
  <div class="america">
      <%= f.select :categories, Quantified::CATEGORIES %>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field :name,  class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Name' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field :metric,  class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Metric' %>
      </div>

    <div id="results">
      <%= f.fields_for :results do |result| %>
      <%= render 'result_fields', :f => result %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add result', f, :results %>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**quantified.rb**

```ruby
class Quantified < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    scope :averaged,  -> { where(categories: 'Monthly Average') }
    scope :instance,  -> { where(categories: 'One-Time Instance') }
    has_many :results
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :results, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

    CATEGORIES = ['Monthly Average', 'One-Time Instance']

end
```

**Github:** https://github.com/RallyWithGalli/ruletoday

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are they submitting the form first? Or do you want the order to change with Javascript (i.e. dynamically as the user changes the first dropdown?)

Comment: It looks as though, in addition to changing the order, choosing a category would also entail changing the data.  I assume the category determines the scope applied to the query when fetching the list of Quantified's to render?  If so, you need to make a server call anyways, so you either do that via AJAX and update the page dynamically, or you set the sort order on the dates on the server side (in your view template) when you're making the request to get all the Quantified's in the given category.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta Do you know how to do either one? I'm not familiar with AJAX, but at this point I would be really happy with either approach, whichever is easier for you or if you're are unable to help than can you suggest an approach out of the two for me to look into?

Comment: @XavierShay this would be before they submit the form. Ideally it would be done dynamically via Javascript but like I said to Amit I would be happy with any approach at this point.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli the latter approach sets the order on the server side, i.e. the server renders the HTML; there's no AJAX/JavaScript.  Are you still interested in either approach?

Comment: Yea @AmitKumarGupta that would work great if you can help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here was to use some jquery provided by the gem that was being used to add the date selects, as well as some jquery of our own

First things first, we rig up the checkboxes with a click() event, that hides anything with the class 'day' if instance is checked, and shows it if not.

```
$('.date-toggle').click(function(){
    if( $(this).attr('id') == 'instance') {
        $('.day').show();
    } else {
        $('.day').hide();
    }
});
```

The trick here is to use the rails date select option `:with_css_classes` on the date select, so that it looks like this:

```
<%= f.date_select :date_value, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :with_css_classes => true, class: 'date-select' %>
```

This causes each included field to get a class corresponding to its name, hence our reference to '.day' up there.

The next important part, however, because he is using a gem called [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to add new elements that included date fields, we had to use some of their jquery event bindings to make sure that the new ones got the right action applied to them.

```
$('#container').on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, insertedItem) {
    if($('#instance').is(':checked')) {
        $('.day').show();
    } else {
        $('.day').hide();
    }
});
```

Technically, the `$('.day').show()` is not necessary, because it defaults to being shown, but this, to me, gets across the intent a little clearer.

Comment: I've never used AJAX before so I'm having a hard time implementing your code. Do I put the 1st code you listed in quantified.coffee? What do I put in place of the comments in the 2nd code listed? You gave me suggestions but whatever I'm doing isn't working. I just need more clarification. Thanks Borromakot!

Comment: Hopefully I can help.  My solution is a pure javascript/jquery solution, and doesn't involve any coffescript.  It would be in quantified.js.  If you have other coffeescript in quantified.coffee, you can make a new file called something like 'quantified_select.js' and require that in your file via `<%= javascript_import_tag "quantified_select.js" %>`.  I will clarify the commented section a little more.  Don't forget to replace the classes and IDs that are used in the javascript example with the actual classes and IDs of your html elements.  Feel free to ask for more help.

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood your question, and will need to revise my answer actually.  Give me a few minutes.  My answer will be much closer to Anti-Fun's up there, but perhaps I can make it a bit simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I think my solution is a little bit messy, but hopefully it gives you an indication of my train of thought and give you something to build upon.

I have changed your categories to work with a radio button group because the select field is a bit weird for 2 elements (subjective I know), to change it back to a select form,simply keep your code as is, but you will need to check the value of the select dropdown using jQuery `.change()` or some other vanilla Javascript way...

You haven't provided any controller names, so I didn't know how to name my JS file, but hopefully you know how to integrate.

IMO, I'm not sure why this needs AJAX, so maybe you can explain to me where that comes in.

#### _form.html.erb

```
<%= Quantified::CATEGORIES.each do |c| %>
  <%= f.radio_button(:category, c) %>
  <%= label(c, c) %>
<% end %>
```

#### _results_fields.html.erb

```
<%= f.date_select :date_value, :order => [:month, :year], class: 'date-select-my' %>
<%= f.date_select :date_value, :order => [:month, :year], class: 'date-select-mdy' %>
```

#### vanilla.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.date-select-mdy').hide();

  $('.date-select-mdy').attr("disabled", true);

  $('input[name$=\category\']').click(function() {
    var target_value;
    target_value = $(this).val;
    if (target_value === 'Monthly Average') {
      $('.date-select-my').show();
      $('.date-select-mdy').hide();
      $('.date-select-my').attr("disabled", false);
      return $('.date-select-mdy').attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $('.date-select-my').hide();
      $('.date-select-mdy').show();
      $('.date-select-my').attr("disabled", true);
      return $('.date-select-mdy').attr("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

#### a_little_bit_of_coffee_because_i_dislike_js.coffee

```
$->
  $('.date-select-mdy').hide()
  $('.date-select-mdy').attr("disabled",true)

  $('input[name$=\category\']').click ->
    target_value = $(this).val
    if target_value == 'Monthly Average'
     $('.date-select-my').show()
     $('.date-select-mdy').hide()
     $('.date-select-my').attr("disabled",false)
     $('.date-select-mdy').attr("disabled",true)
    else
     $('.date-select-my').hide()
     $('.date-select-mdy').show() 
     $('.date-select-my').attr("disabled",true)
     $('.date-select-mdy').attr("disabled",false)
  return
```

Comment: Thank you for answering Christo! I included my github in the question so we can have a better grasp of what went wrong with your suggestions, which look awesome, I just don't know how we can move forward. I created quantifieds.js (aka vanilla) and added your coffee to quantifieds.coffee. In place of "Monthly Average" & "One-Time Instance" I shortened the categories to "Averaged" & "Instance." So with your code and those slight variations I get this error: SyntaxError: [stdin]:4:2: unexpected ->
  (in /Users/galli01anthony/Desktop/RuleToday/app/assets/javascripts/quantifieds.coffee)

Comment: Maybe malformed spaces, I will download your repo and try fix it, then update my answer. I'm sorry I missed the github link.